# get value from textarea using JS and pass it without page reload to server (jsp)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using this piece of code to display a TextArea to my JSP page with a button calling two functions after onclick event.

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<button style="float: right;" onclick="jQuery('#reDiv').load(' #reDiv'); doSth();">Get Text</button>
```

function 1:

```
<div id="reDiv"><%=new java.util.Date().toString()%></div>
```

function 2:

```
<script>
function doSth() {
var text = $("#textarea").val(); //value of textarea
<%=text%> //error
}
</script>
```

Function 1 works fine.

In function 2 I am trying to pass the value, which I just got from the TextArea, to my Server **without reloading the page**. My aim later is to call a method and display the data **without refreshing the page**.

**I know** the error is that JS is Client-Side and JSP is server side.
But how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really bad practice to use scriptlets in your jsp (these things `<% %>`). It was replaced by [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

But yeah the server runs the java in your jsp page before it gets sent to the client. And the javascript runs on the client side after the java has already been executed. On top of that, you cannot directly access javascript variables with scriptlets. You can however do it the other way round but it won't be useful for you in this case.

You mentioned you want to pass the value from your textarea to the your server without your page reloading. This is what AJAX is for.

```
<script>
function doSth() {
var text = $("#textarea").val(); //value of textarea
//<%=text%> //error
sendToServer(text);
}

function sendToServer(text){

  var params = {
      textarea: text
  };
  $.post("YourServletUrl", $.param(params), function(response) {
      // ... handle response here if you have any..
  });     

}
</script>
```

Then in the doPost method of your servlet which has a url mapping of `YourServletUrl` you just do this:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String textarea= request.getParameter("textarea");

        System.out.println(textarea);

}
```